# Как в С++ вызвать функцию qsort() для своей структуры

Tags: c++

Как в С++ вызвать функцию qsort() для своей структуры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat cqs.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // для qsort()
#include <string.h> // для strcmp()

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct my_struct {
  char *arg;
  int argnum;
};

static int compare_my_struct (const void *key1, const void *key2) {
  return strcmp(((my_struct *)key1)->arg, ((my_struct *)key2)->arg);
}

// рассортируем параметры main() по алфавиту
// и выведем их вместе с исходными индексами в av[]
int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  vector<my_struct> v;
  struct my_struct s;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; av[i]; i++) {
    s.argnum = i;
    s.arg = av[i];
    v.push_back(s);
  }

  qsort(&v[0], i, sizeof(s), compare_my_struct);

  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("%d %s\n", v[j].argnum, v[j].arg);

}

avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ cqs.cpp
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out twq qquuq afsgs zyyeye
0 ./a.out
3 afsgs
2 qquuq
1 twq
4 zyyeye
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```